# Play a QAudioBuffer

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

Which is the best way to play `QAudioBuffer` of a format supported by audio card?
Have I to create a `QIODevice` and convert it to raw data manually or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A `QAudioBuffer` is very lightweight handle over a raw `QByteArray`. It is raw data already. You can think of it as a `QByteArray` with a few extra information fields attached to it.

You can write the `QAudioBuffer::data()` to a `QIODevice` returned by `QAudioOutput::start()`.

Comment: The data is not raw, because it is an array of `StereoFrame` that is a struct